# Laptop VGA connection no longer working

Tags: windows-8.1, vga, integrated-graphics, intel-core-i5

While browsing a few websites on my laptop my external monitor that I'm connected to decided to unexpectedly shut off (It's a Dell monitor so it went into 'Power save mode') and from that point on my VGA connection no longer works. I attempted with different VGA cables to no avail, then attempted with a TV screen which presented me with 'No signal'. I then attempted to use an HDMI cable on my TV screen which worked just fine which leads me to believe this is could be problem with my VGA port.

Now upon connecting my VGA cable from my Dell monitor to my laptop the monitor shuts off (enters 'Power save mode'), I see the monitor in my screen options as 'Dell E228WFP' which means it can clearly detect the screen however nothing is being displayed, I've tried 'Duplicate screen', 'Extend screen', and even 'Show desktop only on 2', but still nothing is displayed on the monitor (I've tried all of these on both my Dell monitor and my TV screen).

Unfortunately it is *necessary* that I'm able to use the VGA connection as my laptop screen is greatly damaged and as such I can only see about one quater of my screen, and just my luck that my monitor has a VGA port but unfortunately no HDMI port.

## Specifications

---

**Manufacturer:** Samsung

**Model:** NP270E5E-X01AU

**Operating System:** Windows 8.1

**CPU:** Intel Core i5-3230M

**GPU01 (Integrated):** Intel HD Graphics 4000 (Driver version 10.18.10.3621 16/05/2014)

**GPU02 (Dedicated):** NVIDIA GeForce 710M

Comment: @Ramhound Setup installed [v10.18.10.3621](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/23885/eng/Installation_Readme64.txt) (Timestamp 16/05/2014 9:27:30pm which seems correct enough), restarted laptop and tried again however the problem still persists.

Comment: Intel tricked me. I looked at the driver version and saw `10.18.xx.xxxx` but I know Intel recently released the `15.33.22.64.3621` update.  Leave it to Intel to have two versions for the samething

Comment: Yeah I did a bit of a double take when it told me it was installing v10.18.10.3621

Comment: The good news.  You should have updated anyways.  The bad news that wasn't the problem.  You have confirmed this monitor in question works on another pc right?

Comment: I plugged it into my tower via DVI and it seems to work

Comment: The DVI port working doesn't indicate if the monitor's VGA port works.  Yes;  I know you tried connecting it to a TV, but it worked, when HDMI was used which only tells me that TV might not fully support VGA

Comment: First of all you should check if it is software(driver/os/malware/configuration) issue. As I understand you have other computer available, so fastest way would be to just boot clean system from usb. [Ubuntu on a stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) should do just fine. It won't even take half a hour and will remove one variable from equation.

Comment: I'd try with my tower and the VGA cable but I unfortunally cannot at this moment due to noise problems and it being exactly midnight.

Comment: I know this post is old, but for future visitors it's possible one or more of the pounds in the VGA port on the computer are damaged. This would account for why the computer can detect the monitor but no signal is displayed.